# What is the best way to join a record to a range in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, range, data-modeling, has-many-through

Im working on a Ruby on Rails application (though this is really more of a data structuring question) where I have `Posts`, `Books`, and `Chapters` as models. Suppose a want to be able to reference several chapters in a `Post` and be able to later filter posts by what chapters and books they reference. What would be the best way to join those records together in a way that would be easy to query later on?

My first thought was a typical `has_many :through` association.

```rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_chapters
  has_many :chapters, through: :post_chapters
end

class PostChapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :chapter
end

class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  has_many :post_chapters
  has_many :posts, through: :post_chapters
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :chapters
end
```

This would work perfectly fine if I only needed to store a reference to a few chapters. I would end up with an additional `PostChapter` record for each reference to a chapter. But what happens if someone references Chapters 1 - 1000? Then the application would need to create 1000 records just to be able to tell if Chapter X is included in the reference.

Is there a way to store this as some sort of Range join where it would only store the first and last chapter, but that would still be easy to query later?

I'm using PostgreSQL if that helps at all.

Comment: What are the columns of the Chapter model? Just a number i.e. "5" for chapter 5? Can you show your table schemas? It seems over complicated unless there is more in your Chapters table.

Comment: Also is it realistic to worry about how many rows there are in the join table? Is it realistic to think you'll have books that have more than 100 chapters and that a bunch of posts will reference hundreds of chapters? If you had 5,000 posts that each referenced 100 chapters that's 500,000 rows. That's nothing for Postgres. The first paid tier of Heroku Postgres has 10,000,000 rows. After that they just go by size, not number of rows.

Comment: Depending on your data schema of the various tables you might be better off storing the references as an array of ranges, which can then be stored directly in a Postgres Array column type. It provides for an pretty seamless experience. But in Postgres you have to declare the type of items that will be store in the array and they all must be that type. So you can have an array of integers, and array of strings, but not mixed as you can in Ruby. i.e. [1, "two", 3, 4..8] is legal in Ruby but not in a Postgres Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @beartech your worries about the databases size might be completely unfounded and this is most likely just a case of premature optimization.

But to answer the actual question there are a few ways to store ranges in Postgres. The first "classical" polyglot way is by using two columns and then using between:

```
Post.where("? BETWEEN posts.starting_chaper AND posts.ending_chapter", 99)
```

Since this is just vanilla SQL it will work on any relational database.

Postgres also has a range of [native range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN) (pun intended):

- int4range — Range of integer
- int8range — Range of bigint
- numrange — Range of numeric
- tsrange — Range of timestamp without time zone
- tstzrange — Range of timestamp with time zone
- daterange — Range of date

And these are just the built in types.

Native ranges are not really supported out the box in ActiveRecord but you can use the attributes API introduced in [Rails 5](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/12/11/rails-5-attributes-api.html) to handle typecasting.

```
class Chapter < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :page_range, range: true
end
```

One of the huge advantages here is when it comes to querying as PG knows that this column is actually a range and can create a very effective query plan compared to the previous solution.

Using a JSON or array type here is pretty questionable as you lose all the benefits of the relational model and have none of the benefits of a range column. If an model has multiple ranges I would create a separate join table.

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_chapters
  has_many :chapter_ranges
  has_many :chapters, through: :post_chapters
end

class ChapterRange
  belongs_to :post
  attribute :chapters, range: true
end

# Check if one chapter is contained in range:
Post.joins(:chapter_ranges)
    .where("? @> chapter_ranges.chapters" 10) 

# range is contained by
Post.joins(:chapter_ranges)
    .where("int4range(?, ?) @> chapter_ranges.chapters" 2, 4) 

# overlap
Post.joins(:chapter_ranges)
    .where("int4range(?, ?) && chapter_ranges.chapters" 2, 4)
```